# mysql converting varchar to date

Tags: php, mysql

I already have this code that will return the name and year of hire from a varchar column:

```
select name
     , substring_index
         (substring_index
            (hire_date, '/', 3), '/', -1) as YEAR_OF_HIRE  
  from salesreps;
```

My question is how can I just get specific columns in a varchar column. For example the year of hire on the hire_date(varchar) column has the data:

```
 - 20/12/1986
 - 10/12/1986
 - 12/02/1988
 - 13/01/1990
 - 25/10/1987
```

What I need is just to return data before 1988 so that means it will just return:

```
 - 20/12/1986
 - 10/12/1986
 - 25/10/1987
```

What I need is WITHOUT altering the columns and updating the data in the table.

Comment: It's a school assignment. So it is already designed like that. Not my mistake if it is designed like that.

Comment: It may not be your mistake, but it's still far better to fix somebody else mistake than to propagate it even further

Comment: @mark - Okay sure. I will just alter and update. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select name, YEAR(str_to_date(hire_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) as YEAR_OF_HIRE from salesreps
Where YEAR(str_to_date(hire_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) < 1988
```

Comment: hey thank you very much! I actually edited your code a while ago and got an answer, then when I saw you edited, I tried and I got a better answer. Thank you very much!! :D

Comment: I actually used this before you edited your answer:

select name, (case when YEAR(str_to_date(hire_date, '%d/%m/%Y')) 
< 1988 then hire_date else NULL end) as YEAR_OF_HIRE from salesreps;

Comment: I think this is the last edit to my solution ;)
I try it on my own and worked as desired

Comment: Yes it worked for me and it shows better results. Thank you very much! I highly appreciated your response answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$years = explode($row['hire_date'], "/");

IF ($years[2] <= 1998){
    //do stuff
}
```